# Rails PayPal Checkout SDK Store Request Body in View instead of Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm running Rails 5.2 and I currently have my PayPal Checkout setup like this:

View:

```
paypal.Buttons({
      
      env: "#{ENV['PAYPAL_ENV']}",

      createOrder: async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/create_order', {method: 'POST'});
        const responseData = await response.json();
        return responseData.token;
      },
```

Controller:

```
def create_order
    price = '100.00'
   
    request = PayPalCheckoutSdk::Orders::OrdersCreateRequest::new
    request.request_body({
      :intent => 'CAPTURE',
      :purchase_units => [
        {
          :amount => {
            :currency_code => 'USD',
            :value => price
          }
        }
      ]
    })
    begin
      response = @client.execute request
      order = Order.new(order_params)
      order.price_cents = price.to_i
      order.token = response.result.id
      if order.save
        return render :json => {:token => response.result.id}, :status => :ok
      end
    rescue PayPalHttp::HttpError => ioe
      return render html: ERROR_MESSAGE
    end
  end
```

BUT... I would rather handle the request body in the JavaScript like so:

```
 createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      
      return actions.order.create({
        
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: document.getElementById('payprice').value
          }
        }]
      });
      
    },
```

How can I setup my controller so that it still gives me the PayPal token... but it accepts the request body from the JavaScript in the view instead of the way it's set up now? Or... failing that... How can I get the form data from the view (price) into the controller to replace the "price" that's there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preston PHX deserves a lot of credit for pointing me in the right direction... but it was my friend Gary who solved this little dilemma two hours ago:

view:

```
 paypal.Buttons({
      
      env: "#{ENV['PAYPAL_ENV']}",
      createOrder: async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/create_order', {method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
    body: JSON.stringify({"price" : document.getElementById('amount').value})
  });
        const responseData = await response.json();
        return responseData.token;
      },
```

controller:

```
def create_order
    price = params[:amount]
    request = PayPalCheckoutSdk::Orders::OrdersCreateRequest::new
    request.request_body({
      :intent => 'CAPTURE',
      :purchase_units => [
        {
          :amount => {
            :currency_code => 'USD',
             :value => price
          }
        }
      ]
    })
```

And that's it. That completely answers the question of how to get the price into the controller... and how to get the price from the form into the javascript so that it gets posted to the controller.

It amazes me that after a month of searching I never saw a single mention anywhere of how to do this. I would imagine there are a LOT of apps out there where you would want a user to choose the amount they are going to pay and the currency.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want your JS code to call your Ruby code to obtain the order token -- and probably later to capture the transaction after approval, as well.

You need a server-side integration pattern like this: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You'll then need to create two routes on your server that your JS code can call, and point it toward them.

Comment: No. I already have the token and the two routes and all that. What I've done is a slightly modified version of this: https://www.davidangulo.xyz/simple-paypal-checkout-in-ruby-on-rails-using-orders-api-v2/ which is essentially a copy of what you have above.

Comment: Then you already have the correct solution which does not involve `actions.order.create()` and instead uses fetch to the server. I guess you are asking how to include the price as a parameter. It can be part of the fetch request body or part of the URL route.

Comment: Ok. Well if you add how to add it to the fetch request body in the script... and how to then retrieve it in the controller... I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: So far I've attempted const response = await fetch('/create_order', {method: 'POST', "amount" : payprice}); and in the controller: "price = params[:amount]" but I receive the error: "Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0"

Comment: The linked server pattern has an example of transmitting `data.orderID` as part of the URL path.  For an example of sending the same in a JSON-formatted request body, see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/#on-the-client . You need to send your data in JSON format if you're going to read it as such

Comment: I'm not sure how to communicate to you where the confusion is... See I would actually PREFER to use `actions.order.create()` because at least that actually works. In fact... if I replace the "fetch" with that... then I have everything I need but the token. Use the fetch instead? I've got everything but the price. I have seen the examples... but I am confused as to how to put it all together. I keep getting the syntax wrong somehow. So... if you would write a complete response for how to do this... then I will accept your answer.

Comment: But I think you're right... it would be best to just use the fetch without actions.order.create()... but that brings me right back where I started which is retrieving the "price" in the controller. I believe I know how to send it: const response = await fetch('/create_order', {method: 'POST', "price_cents" : 365}); but I seem to be having infinite trouble receiving it in the controller.

Comment: Use JSON.stringify on the data object to send